# Jquery .value returning undefined in function to return input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I know this is going to be really basic, as I can appreciate how simple this should be - but I've got myself all twisted up.

I'm just trying to make a searchbar function. This is the input -

```html
<input class="form-control me-2 header__searchbar comic__search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" style="width: 15rem; margin-left: 2rem;">
```

This is the code (so far), but I cant get it to return the value.

```js
var searchbar = $(".comic__search");
var searchBarVal = ""

$("body").on("keyup", searchbar, function() {
  searchBarVal = searchbar.value;
  console.log(searchbar.value);
})
```

Thanks all

Comment: hi @RoryMcCrossan - Thanks for your answer though I'm now even more confused. The eventhandler is firing correctly as it is, it's just not returning the value in the console.log (i'm aware that I'm not currently returning anything at present, literally just trying to get the value working)

Comment: I added an answer for you below outlining the issues and how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two separate issues here.

Firstly you cannot add a delegated event handler by providing a jQuery object in the second argument of [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on), so the event is not being bound correctly (it will work for the `.comic__search` elements that are in the DOM when the event is bound, but not ones dynamically created at a later time, which is the point of a delegated handler). Change `searchbar` to a string instead.

Secondly jQuery's method is [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val), not `value`.

```js
var searchBarVal = "";

$("body").on("keyup", '.comic__search', function() {
  searchBarVal = $(this).val();
})

$('button').on('click', () => console.log(searchBarVal));
```

```css
input {
  width: 15rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control me-2 header__searchbar comic__search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />

<button>Check value</button>
```

Finally, note that you're not 'returning' anything here, you're just updating the variable in the higher scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `.value` to `.val()` because `searchbar` is a `jQuery` object.

```js
var searchbar = $(".comic__search");
var searchBarVal = "";

$("body").on("keyup", searchbar, function() {
  searchBarVal = searchbar.val();
  console.log(searchbar.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example, searchbar is a jquery object and to access the value of a html input element within jquery object, you have to call the function val():

```
var searchbar = $(".comic__search");
var searchBarVal = "";

$("body").on("keyup", function() {
  searchBarVal = searchbar.val();
  console.log(searchbar.val());
})
```

or access the html elment directly through the jquery wrapper:

```
var searchbar = $(".comic__search");
var searchBarVal = "";

$("body").on("keyup", function() {
  searchBarVal = searchbar.get(0).value;
  console.log(searchbar.get(0).value);
})
```

optionally, you can also access the object directly without any jquery:

```
var searchbar = document.querySelector(".comic__search");
var searchBarVal = "";

btn.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  searchBarVal = searchbar.value;
  console.log(searchbar.value);
})
```